# Problem in remove sqlite connection in QT

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I've got following error when i want to remove my QSqlDatabase that connected to the Sqltie:

**QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'cnnDFP' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.**

*cnnDFP is my connection name

How can i fix this? please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory management problem when using SQLite in QT with QThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528264/memory-management-problem-when-using-sqlite-in-qt-with-qthread)

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing you're code, so it is difficult to guess what is wrong. Anyway, have you read the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase? Did you close all the queries before trying to remove the connection?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, How can i close queries?

Comment: Sorry but... have you read the documentation? The correct way to do it is reported clearly after the line stating "the correct way to do it". I don't know how to clarify that. Or are you saying that doing it that way didn't solve the problem?